# document.url issue in IE

Tags: javascript, window.location

```
function drawCaptcha() {
    var absURL = document.URL.substr(0, document.URL.lastIndexOf('#'));

     // Internet Explorer 6-11
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
        // Edge 20+
    var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
    if(isIE || isEdge){
        var absURL = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf('#'));
    }
    console.log("absURL==",absURL);
    document.getElementById('captchaImage').setAttribute('src',
            absURL + 'web/gencptch');
    //document.getElementById('captchaImage').setAttribute('src', '/epa-web/web/gencptch');

}
```

Hi 
 I am trying to generate a captcha image by clicking on the button. It is perfectly working in chrome and Mozilla but there is issue in IE.

When I tried to debug in IE I found the value of document.URL is different from chrome and Mozilla .

In chrome its value is `localhost:8080/login/#` , while in IE it is coming as `" "` . I tried to replace `document.URL` with `window.location.href`, but no luck. I tried hard but not getting the reason why the image is not displaying in IE. In network section I see the service is not getting called don't know why !!!

**EDIT** :-

Is this issue is because of JQuery

since when I am loading the page I am calling a function

```
$(document).ready(
            function() {
                var absURL = document.URL.substr(0, document.URL
                        .lastIndexOf('#'));
                document.getElementById('captchaImage').setAttribute('src',
                        absURL + 'web/gencptch');
            });
```

Any help is appreciated !!!

Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce it, is it any specific version of IE?

Comment: yes IE Edge it is

Comment: Sorry, that's not actually a specific version. That means just *the latest that **you** have*.

Comment: Hi , I have updated my code please check it

Comment: document.getElementById('captchaImage').setAttribute('src',
            absURL + 'web/gencptch') is not working in IE

Comment: setAttribute is often problematic, especially in IE. Try elementReference.src = "value" instead.

Comment: Remember IE 11 is the last version of IE. Edge is a different browser and is not called IE.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're trying to do honestly...

```
function drawCaptcha() {
    document.getElementById('captchaImage').setAttribute('src','test');
    var urlHash = location.href.lastIndexOf('#');
    if ( urlHash === -1 ) urlHash = location.href.length;
    var absURL = location.href.substr(0, urlHash);
    document.getElementById('captchaImage').setAttribute('src',
            absURL + 'web/gencptch');
}
```

This should work just fine. Be sure you're actually having `drawCaptcha()` called.

`location.href` is a strongly known location across all browsers.

I have an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jr9sbj8h/1/). I tested with IE "Edge" (v11, executable v11.1000.14931.0) on Windows 10 as well as Microsoft *Edge* (v14, executable also v11.0.14931.1000) on Windows 10. Inspected the element, the `src` attribute was correct for a few given scenarios.

Comment: You might want to put IE Edge in quotes, as IE 11 is the last version of IE. Edge is a different browser and is not called IE.

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft Internet Explorer "Edge" vs Microsoft *Edge*. Why did they do this. I liked Spartan just fine.